# How to add currency attribute to .ClientTemplate

Tags: gridview, attributes, kendo-ui

How can I set this up to where it is formatted as currency as apposed to a boring int? ($0.00 instead of 0)

```
columns.Bound(o => o.BasePremium).Title("Base Prem:").ClientTemplate("#= BasePremium #" +
                    "<input class='k-input k-textbox' type='hidden' name='Locations[#= index(data)#].BasePremium' value='#= BasePremium #' />"
                  ).Format("{0:c}");
```

The `.Format` at the end doesnt seem to do the trick.

Comment: "Opposed", not "apposed". The way you stated it, the currency value would be displayed _next to_ the boring int.

Answer (score 7):

Since you're using `.ClientTemplate` it will disregard `.Format()`.  Instead use something like this:

```
#:kendo.toString(BasePremium, 'c2')#
```

which will equal $123.45

You can read more about it here: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/numberformatting

Answer (score 1):

One thing I figured out is you should pass a decimal to kendo.toString() not a string, it does not work otherwise.

```
 kendo.toString("99", 'c') 
"99" 
kendo.toString(99, 'c') 
"$99.00"
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `#BasePremium.toString("c")#` would be to use Kendo's `#kendo.format("{0:c}", BasePremium)#`, which works like .Net's `String.Format()` and Kendo MVC's `.Format()` functions.

Comment: kendo.format helped me achieve the accounting negative values like -$123.00  will now show ($123.00).